# How to VBA Excel Macro part of a string

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently busy with Excel tooling and learning a lot but i got a question. Currently i have a couple rows with data in the rows.  In the rows there is a lot of data but i need a specific part of the row. Of course i can delete it all manually but to do that for 3000 rows i will be wasting a lot of time.

Can any one help me with a macro that filters data. The data i need is between [ and ] so for example [data]

I hope you guys can help me out and if you need more information just ask me! I hope you guys can help me!

***Example String ROW:***

```
[Sandwitch]><xsd:element name="T8436283"
```

**So what do i need?**

So i need a macro that only gets the Sandwitch out of it and paste it in the B column. The string with all the information stays at column A and the Sandwitch goes to Column B and that for all rows.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague.  Please add sample data and expected results.

Comment: Are you saying you have a single cell with info such as `words words [important words here] words words` and you just want to extract `important words here`?

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. I added a example. So basically in my string there is a lot of information and i need only the information between the [ and the ]. The other information is not necessary. The String is in column A and only the Sandwitch (In my example) Needs to be placed in column B.

Comment: Love the title, reminds me of The Matrix or Hong Kong Fuey.  Anyway.... `=MID(A1,FIND("[",$A$1)+1,FIND("]",$A$1)-FIND("[",$A$1)-1)`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook + for Hong Kong Fuey :-) and a solution too.  All your noun are belong to verb.

Comment: @Joffan - showing my age now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Find/Replace
     1) Copy data in another column (just saving original copy)
     2) Perform Find/Replace "*["
     3) Perform Find/Replace "]"
          Now you have data which was between [].

Option 2: Use formulas
     1) Lets assume that original data in Column "A"
     2) Apply this formula in column "B" which will extract data between []
        =MID(A1,FIND("[",A1)+1,FIND("]",A1)-FIND("[",A1)-1)

Option 3: Macro
     If it is absolutely needed, I can help create a macro, otherwise try first two easier options.

Comment: Thank you! Do you also have a formula for between the " and " The 2nd option worked good for me! But i want also in Column C the information that is between " and " if you could help me with that then you made my Day!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your feet wet in Regular Expressions, the following code will take you there. You have to add a reference to the VB Scripting Library

```
Tools > References > Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
```

Then the code is as follows:

```
Sub textBetweenStuffs()

    Dim str As String
    Dim regEx As RegExp
    Dim m As Match
    Dim sHolder As MatchCollection
    Dim bracketCollection As Collection
    Dim quoteCollection As Collection

    Set regEx = New RegExp

    'Matches anything in between an opening bracket and first closing bracket
    regEx.Pattern = "\[(.*?\])"
    str = "[Sandwitch]><xsd:element name=""T8436283"""

    'populates matches into match collection
    Set sHolder = regEx.Execute(str)

    Set bracketCollection = New Collection

    'loop through values in match collection to do with as you wish
    For Each m In sHolder
        bracketCollection.Add m.Value
    Next i

    Set sHolder = Nothing

    'get values between Quotations
    regEx.Pattern = "\"(.*?\")"

    'populates matches into match collection
    Set sHolder = regEx.Execute(str)

    Set quoteCollection = New Collection

    'loop through values in match collection to do with as you wish
    For Each m In sHolder
        quoteCollection.Add m.Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A general purpose "find element in **s** starting **x** up to next **y**":

```
Function GenExtract(FromStr As String, _
                    StartSep As String, EndSep As String) _
                As Variant

Dim StPos As Long
Dim EnPos As Long

GenExtract = CVErr(xlErrNA)
If StartSep = "" Or EndSep = "" Then Exit Function 'fail
StPos = InStr(1, FromStr, Left(StartSep, 1))
If StPos = 0 Or StPos = Len(FromStr) Then Exit Function 'fail
EnPos = InStr(StPos + 1, FromStr, Left(EndSep, 1))
If EnPos = 0 Then Exit Function 'fail

GenExtract = Mid(FromStr, StPos + 1, EnPos - StPos - 1)

End Function
```

If the two separators are the same, as per quotes, it gives the first string enclosed by those.